# make xml file using xslt and html

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have HTML page that I created using xslt and an xml file. now In this html file, there is the option to change some values, so after these changes I want to generate xml content with these changes. How can I do that? Is there an easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for somethig like XMLForm :- http://www.datamech.com/XMLForm/